# how do i find $\max\{x+z\}$ and $\max\{1+y^2\}$ where ?$x\ge0 $,$ y\ge0$,$ z\ge0$ and$xy+xz+yz=1 $

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

how  compute  $\max\{x+z\}$ and $\max\{1+y^2\}$? such that $x$,$y$,$z$ satisfied 
$$\begin{cases}
xy+xz+yz=1   &  \\
x\ge0  \\
y\ge0\\
z\ge0\\
\end{cases} $$ i face with this problem when i try solve [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413683/show-that-frac-1-sqrtxy-frac-1-sqrtyz-frac-1-sqrtzx-geq2)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

We can try  [Lagrange Multiplier](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeMultiplier.html)

Alternatively, we know if $A+B+C=\frac\pi2, \sum \tan A\tan B=1$

As $x,y,z\ge0,$ we can choose $A,B,C\in [0,\frac\pi2]$

Now, $1+y^2=1+\tan^2C=\sec^2C$ which tends to $\infty$ as $C\to\infty$

$x+z=\tan A+\tan C$  which tends to $\infty$ as $A$ or $C\to\infty$

Comment: i edit my question please see once again my question

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo, looking into it

Comment: if if $x+z$ tend to $\infty$ how do u justify minimum value of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}+2\frac{1}{\sqrt{y+1}\sqrt{x+z}}$  in this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413683/show-that-frac-1-sqrtxy-frac-1-sqrtyz-frac-1-sqrtzx-geq2

Answer (score 0):

$(x+z)$ is unbounded above.Reason: Let $M>0$ be given and let $y=0,z=M,x=\frac{1}{M}$ Then $(x+z)>M$ so it is unbounded above.

$(1+y^2)$ is also unbounded. Reason take $y=M,z=0,x=\frac{1}{M}$ then $(1+y^2)>M$